# Should the function that operates on the object return it?

Tags: object-oriented, php, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

Should the function that operates on the object return it?

Shortened example:

```
class Example1
{
    public function method($a, $b)
    {
        $result = new Result($a, $b);

        $this->multiplication($result, 2);

        return $result;
    }

    private function multiplication(Result $object, $value)
    {
        $object->multi($value);
    }
}

class Example2
{
    public function method($a, $b)
    {
        $result = new Result($a, $b);

        $result = $this->multiplication($result, 2);

        return $result;
    }

    private function multiplication(Result $object, $value)
    {
        return $object->multi($value);
    }
}
```

Both classes give the same results, but which style should I use?

The second example is clearer, but on the other hand everyone should know that the objects are passed through the reference.

Comment: I would say no. Returning the object could indicate immutability and another developer could count on that. So either clone the object, modify the new instance and return it or do not return anything.

Comment: What's the result of `$object->multi($value)`? You seem to be assuming that it will be `$object`. By your rule, every function should `return $this`

Comment: In theory, a method should return only necessary data not all data.

Answer (score 3):

The `multiplication` method is in the wrong class. If a method doesn't need `$this` then it should be moved into a class that it *does* need. Your `method` methods (both of them) use `$this` but only because multiplication is in the wrong class.

Now on to your actual question rather than the sample code.

If a method returns something other than `$this` it should not modify the state of this. If a method returns $this or doesn't return any value, then it *should* modify `$this`.

Since none of the methods you wrote modify the state of $this, they should all return something other than $this.

The above is known as [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

So now, should a method that modifies the state of this return this or return nothing? Returning this consistently allows for easy chaining of methods `$obj->fn1()->fn2()` but limits the ability of methods to perform asynchronous operations which means they can't act as proxies for some external source. It's a tradeoff. Personally, I prefer the latter. I see no point in ever returning `$this` because the caller already has a reference to this and therefore doesn't need you to pass one back to it.